# Can't fully expand projects and targets list in Xcode 7

Tags: macos, xcode

I can't seem to fully expand the project and targets list in Xcode 7. I can toggle the 'Hide/Show Projects and Targets' but when when it is supposed to show projects and targets it just shows a sliver. Also I can't drag this pane open any further. I'm asking here instead of SO since this question isn't about programming.

- Xcode: 7.0
- OS X: 10.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's just a layout (probably AutoLayout) issue with Xcode on smaller screens. When I close some panels or view Xcode on larger screen I'm able to expand and resize the projects and targets panel.